# Using Request and Response in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, http-redirect

**Here is my Form**

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'register', 'class' => 'form-signin')) }}

// form username , password .. fields here
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**And the route is**

```
Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@registeruser');
```

**And the Controller is**

```
public function registeruser()
    {

    //validation

  return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validator); // main

    }
```

As, i am being redirected i won't be having any fields that is filled in the form.

I know that i should use request and response for this.

I tried with below response, even this is a horrible try.

```
return Response::view('home')->header('utf-8', $messages);
```

But while doing above even the page reloads and the values filled in the form disappears. How can i through the errors without the values disappears ?

Is there a way to have filled the fields in the form as entered ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `->withInput()`

```
return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()->withErrors($validator); // main
```

Comment: Thanks. At the same time i use, $input = Input::all(); and var_dump($input); it shows array(0)  and the form values disappears How can i fix this ?

Comment: You need to use `Input::old()` to get the old values they used

Comment: Thanks I am getting the old values as array, How can i get the particular variable i.e., firstname of that, I tried echo $input->('firstname');
But  i end with error

Comment: I think you can do `Input::old('firstname')`?

Comment: Awesome, Accepting your answer !! To display in the userfield i am checking in php using isset display Input::old('firstname') else empty like that, But is that a good process ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Input::flash()

```
public function registeruser()
{
    //validation
    Input::flash();

    return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validator); // main
}
```

Then in the controller method that handles the redirect you can access the old input with Input::old(). Using Input::all() will only return data for the current request.

You can also use the ->withInput() chained method on your return line.

Read more about it here http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have a validation like this:

```
$validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);
```

Then you need to do that:

```
if( $validation->fails() )
{
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->messages());
}
```

note the `Redirect::back()` that allows you to get back to your form and fill it automatically with user input

Comment: Thanks, It allows me to get back to the form  but the input values disappears, and i am using Input:old() as Shift Exchange suggests, Thanks

Comment: You do not need to use Input::old if your route is declared as resource, Laravel do it for you.

Comment: Glupponi : How can i make the route declared as resource  ?

Comment: Have a look here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers